# Where do I go to purchase Chinese manhua?

Tags: resources, merchandise

I would like to purchase a manhua titled, "Yinhe Biduan" but I am having a very hard time finding here in the States.

Can anyone direct me to an internet store?

Comment: Apparently, you can purchase anything from the international Amazons. However, It might be a bit troubling to navigate through. Try to copy & paste the, Chinese characters onto the search. Hope, this helped - Chrissy

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the name, I think it's

---

### 銀河彼端

---

in Chinese so feel free to copy and paste on Amazon or Ebay, I'm pretty sure you'll get your manga.

Do inform me if this doesn't qualify as an answer, I'll delete right away.

Comment: All though this translation can be helpful to the author, it wouldn't hurt to actually paste it into amazon/ebay your self and include a link.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Taobao (Chinese Ebay) and think [here](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.16.7734739dykQ018&id=570108585310&ns=1&abbucket=15#detail) is what you want.